# How can I make it automatically input particular keyword into text field when a user click a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a HTML form. I'd like to add a button, with which a particular keyword will be automatically input into certain input field(Just like Twitter's reply)
Then it also jump to certain link.

How can I implement that with jQuery or Javascript?

**HTML(Form part)**

```
<a name="comment_part"></a>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/John/comments" class="new_comment" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_comment" method="post">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="vvwHbqyiDXv0Sv5NrbPP5kfdwhovbHkkOUm2/2uJdNs=" />
    <input class="chat_input" id="body_input" name="comment[body]" type="text" />  
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>   
</form>
```

**HTML(Button part)**

```
keyword = "@John "
(here, I want to show a button. If a user click on it, `@John ` will be automatically input into the input field above `input class="chat_box" id="body_input"` then jump to a link `<a name="comment_part"></a>`)
```

How can I archive this with jQuery or Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where that keyword is coming from, just attach it to your button as a data attribute...

```
  <button class='yourbutton' data-keyword="@john">YOUR BUTTON</button>
```

Then the Jquery, goes inside your document ready code...

```
$('.yourbutton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();    
$('#body_input').val($(this).data('keyword'));
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('a[name="comment_part"]').offset().top -100 }, 'slow'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for an answer:) Could you add one more step to jump to a name link after that???

Comment: @KyleK, targeting an element by the `id` attribute for an inner page jump isn't considered valid markup. You need to target the `name` attribute in order make it valid and ensure that bots will correctly crawl and index the page.

Comment: @MKK, be advised that the proposed solution relies on a non-native jQuery library. You'll need to include it in order to utilize `scrollTo`. Proceed with caution, however, because there's no guarantee that it'll be compatible with your version of Rails. Alternatively, you can use `.scrollTop()` as the previous commenter suggests.

Comment: @zeantsoi Thanks for additional advice:) That helps me a lot!

Comment: Why did you uncheck my answer???  I have changed the scrollTo to use ScrollTop with a nice animation?  I took the time to change my answer to suit your needs....

Answer (score 1):

Create a button and assign it a unique `id` attribute:

```
<button type="button" id="username" value="#{@keyword}">Populate the chat box</button>
```

Then, in jQuery, listen for a click on that button; when it's clicked, pass the `value` attribute and assign it to `input.chat_input#body_input`:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('button#username').click(function () {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".chat_input#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));
     });
});
```

EDIT:

If instead you want the button click to jump to a name link, you can use Rails' [`button_to` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

```
<%= button_to "Populate the chat box", "#name", :id => :username, :value => @keyword %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for an answer:) Could you add one more step to jump to a name link after that???

Comment: Is it possible to use a link instead of button?

Comment: something like this `link_to "<span class='btn btn-success'>Reply</span>".html_safe , new_messages_path(username), :id => :username, :value => user`

Comment: I will create new question "How can I do this in Rails". You answer includes the way of it with Rails solution. So please come to new question and answer the same:)

Comment: please come to new question please :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130315/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-input-particular-keyword-into-input-field-when-its