# How can I create a "link" to input particular keyword into input field when it's clicked?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on Rails application.
If you click on that button, it automatically input @keyword into `body_input`
I want it with link_to instead of button_to.
How can I?

**View**

```
<%= button_to "Populate the chat box", "#name", :id => :username, :value => @keyword %>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('button#username').click(function () {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".chat_input#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));
     });
});
```

**Additional Info**(This is output javascript in HTML)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[     
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
             $('button#username').click(function () {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $(".chat_input#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));
             });
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two are equivalent in function, though not in markup:

```
<%= link_to "Populate the chat box", "#name", :id => :username, :value => @keyword %>
<%= button_to "Populate the chat box", "#name", :id => :username, :value => @keyword %>
```

As commenter [PSL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl) astutely points out, if you decide to utilize a `link_to` to jump to a named anchor, you'll need to modify your jQuery function to remove `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a#username').click(function () {
         $(".chat_input#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting answer:) Can you do that with link_to instead of button_to?

Comment: Yes. And how about an upvote if it's been particularly helpful? It's essentially answering two questions in one.

Comment: Did this work? If so, would you kindly consider accepting it as such?

Comment: yes it is. Stackoverflow asks me to wait for 3 more mins to update your answer:)

Comment: @zeantsoi it creates a link `user/John_Smith#name` but it won't jump to `#name` even if I click on it. Why??

Comment: @MKK remove `e.preventDefault();` to make the anchor #jump happen

Comment: @PSL, very right. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: @PSL I added additional info to my question. I still have 2 problems 1. It won't jump to `#name`, 2. It won't automatically input into "name" :(

Comment: @MKK, you need to target the `<a>` tag in your jQuery selector in order for the automatic input to work. As for the inner jump issue, it's probably something related to the link path. If you have continued issues you'd like to troubleshoot, I'd recommend that we take this discussion into a chat room.

Comment: @zeantsoi Thanks so much let's do that

Comment: How can we start discussion here

Comment: I thought the number of comments have to reach maximum number of comments in order to start discussion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31815/discussion-between-zeantsoi-and-mkk)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar wit ROR syntax but try this:

```
<%= link_to "Populate the chat box", "#name", :id => :username, :value => @keyword %>
```

and (Id must be unique  so in the jquery selector on ID refrain from using tagname#Id just use ID)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {  
     $('#username').click(function () {  
         e.preventDefault();
         $(".chat_input#body_input").val($(this).attr('value'));
     });
});
```

Comment: FYI, Ruby syntax delimits arguments by comma, so you'll want to insert one between `"Populate the chat box`" and `"#name"`.